# Phrase "breeding up" in Animal Farm

Tags: word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

I am reading George Orwell's *Animal Farm* and here I don't understand what the meaning of ***breeding up*** is here.

> You cows that I see before me, how many thousands of gallons of milk have you given during this last year? And what has happened to that milk which should have been **breeding up** sturdy calves? Every drop of it has gone down the throats of our enemies [humans].

Is it *breeding up* similar to word *feed*?

Comment: Do you know what "breed"/"breeding" means based on what's in a dictionary? That's the place to start before you ask a question here, and if that didn't solve your question, an explanation of why it didn't should be included in the question itself.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breed_up; https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/breed 4A

Comment: I would definitely use "bringing up" or "raising". Chambers has "train or bring up" as a definition of "breed" (not "breed up") but that would usually be very confusing. In this sentence the meaning is only obvious from context. This seems unusually sloppy for Orwell. Maybe the meaning has changed although this wasn't written that long ago.

Comment: A bit more research does confirm his use of this, but not usual usage these days.

Comment: "Breed up" also used in [Michigan State Farmers' Institutes, Issue 2, Michigan. State Board of Agriculture, 1896](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Michigan_State_Farmers_Institutes/_EHOAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22breed%20up%22&pg=PA139&printsec=frontcover) on Google Books to mean something like "breed with the intention of producing better livestock", "perform selective breeding".

Comment: It is just *an alternative to feeding and was invented by the author*. And it works fine.

Comment: Lambie's correct, this is a colloquialism.